# Why are my Styled Components' generated class names colliding?

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components

I usually build my Styled Components with a root `<Container>` tag. However, in my current project, class names generated by Styled Components with identical names are colliding.

For example, `<FooWidget>` will be styled with the `Container` styles of `<BarWidget>`.

This happens unpredictably, but deterministically. I.e. not all `<Container>`s collide, but when they do, they do so in the same way every time. I can fix this by changing the components' names or root elements, but then this eliminates the scoping benefits of CSS-in-JS.

I've never had this problem before, which makes me suspect in may have to do with server side rendering on Next.js, which I'm using for the first time. If I restart the dev server, everything will display correctly on the initial render, but then break and stay broken on first refresh.

I installed Styled Components according to the Next.js guide. I found this bug on Github that may be related: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3125.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?